# Get the arraylist object from the model class using commons BeanUtils

Tags: java, reflection, jax-rs, apache-commons-beanutils

In my model class I have a private field of type `ArrayList`, when I try to get the `ArrayList` using `BeanUtils`, it fails saying no such method, can someone please be kind enough to explain why this is happening?

The code is as follows:

```
public class ApplicationListDTO  implements DTO {  

  private Integer count = null;      
  private String next = null;      
  private String previous = null;      
  private List<ApplicationInfoDTO> list = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfoDTO>();
  private long lastUpdatedTime = 0L;
  private long createdTime = 0L;

  /**
  * gets and sets the lastUpdatedTime for ApplicationListDTO
  **/
  @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
  public long getLastUpdatedTime(){
    return lastUpdatedTime;
  }
  public void setLastUpdatedTime(long lastUpdatedTime){
    this.lastUpdatedTime=lastUpdatedTime;
  }

  /**
  * gets and sets the createdTime for a ApplicationListDTO
  **/

  @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
  public long getCreatedTime(){
    return createdTime;
  }
  public void setCreatedTime(long createdTime){
    this.createdTime=createdTime;
  }

  /**
   * Number of applications returned.\n
   **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Number of applications returned.\n")
  @JsonProperty("count")
  public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
  }
  public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

    /**
   * Link to the next subset of resources qualified.\nEmpty if no more resources are to be returned.\n
   **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Link to the next subset of resources qualified.\nEmpty if no more resources are to be returned.\n")
  @JsonProperty("next")
  public String getNext() {
    return next;
  }
  public void setNext(String next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

    /**
   * Link to the previous subset of resources qualified.\nEmpty if current subset is the first subset returned.\n
   **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Link to the previous subset of resources qualified.\nEmpty if current subset is the first subset returned.\n")
  @JsonProperty("previous")
  public String getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }
  public void setPrevious(String previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }

    /**
   **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonProperty("list")
  public List<ApplicationInfoDTO> getList() {
    return list;
  }
  public void setList(List<ApplicationInfoDTO> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

and the code for method invocation is as follows:

```
Object object = ((ResponseImpl) message.getContent(List.class).get(0)).getEntity();
BeanUtils.getProperty(object,"list");
```

Answer (score 0):

`BeanUtils.getProperty(..)` [returns String](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-), so it is not what you need.

You can do it without any support library:

```
try {
    Object object = ((ResponseImpl) message.getContent(List.class).get(0)).getEntity();
    Field field   = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("list");

    List<Object> list = field.get(object);

    [...]
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you can do it with `FieldUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/). Here is an example:

```
try {
    Object object = ((ResponseImpl) message.getContent(List.class).get(0)).getEntity();
    Field field   = FieldUtils.getField(object.getClass(), "list", true);

    List<Object> list = field.get(object);

    [...]
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```